# Quering for Test folder that contains a whitespace using rally_api

Tags: api, rally

I’m doing a tool to create Test folders (test suites) and test cases automatically from a xml file that a Jenkins job provides me.
Probably is a silly thing but I cannot find the solution, the thing is when the test folder name contains a white space, I’m not able to query it to see if already exists. I’ve trid to escape the whitespace and also encode it as url but nothing happens.

```
    test_suite_name = ts_line["name"]

    if test_suite_name.match(/\s/)
            #test_suite_name_nows = test_suite_name.gsub(/ /,"\\ \\")
            test_suite_name_nows = URI::encode(test_suite_name)

    end
    #==================== Querying the test suite in Rally ==========================
    test_suite_query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new({:type => :testfolder, :query_string => "(Name = #{test_suite_name_nows})"})
```

Do you know which should be the format for being able to query test folder names as “Test folder1”??

I always get:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rally_api-0.9.14/lib/rally_api/rally_json_connection.rb:153:in `send_request':  (StandardError)
Error on request - https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/testfolder.js - 
{:errors=>["Could not parse: Cannot parse expression \"Version tests\" as a query"]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the format:

```
query.query_string = "(Name = \"My Test Folder 1\")"
```

and a full example:

```
require 'rally_api'

#Setup custom app information
headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
headers.name = "find test folder"
headers.vendor = "NickM RallyLab"
headers.version = "1.0"

# Connection to Rally
config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username] = "user@co.com"
config[:password] = "1984"
config[:workspace] = "W"
config[:project] = "P"
config[:headers] = headers #from RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :test_folder
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID"
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/workspace/12345.js" } #use yoru OID
query.project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/project/67890.js" } #user yoru OID
query.page_size = 200 #optional - default is 200
query.limit = 1000 #optional - default is 99999
query.project_scope_up = false
query.project_scope_down = true
query.order = "Name Asc"
query.query_string = "(Name = \"My Test Folder 1\")"

results = @rally.find(query)

results.each do |t|
    puts "Name: #{t["Name"]}, FormattedID: #{t["FormattedID"]}"
    t.read
    #.............
end
```